# How to configure animated in custom segue in iOS using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a created a custom segue like below

```
class DismissSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
override func perform() {
    sourceController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

In some scenarios I want to dismiss my currentVC without animation but in some cases with animation. How does it possible? I tried setting up @IBInspectable but no luck it doesn't show up property in storyboard. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you're dismissing, you'd generally just specify `true` or `false` for the `dismiss` call. And then it takes care of it for us. Or do you need to do an unwind segue for some reason? Or are you doing custom transitions (e.g. `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`)? Perhaps you can describe the broader problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: actually I have edited it ...I have created a custom segue where it has animation always true but now I have to change it false/true depends on the situation. How can I make it editable ? @Rob

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

- If you are determined to use your `DismissSegue`, you can, in Swift 3:

  ```
  class DismissSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
      override func perform() {
          let animated = (source as? OptionalAnimation)?.animateDismiss ?? true
          source.dismiss(animated: animated)
      }
  }
  ```

  Or Swift 2.3:

  ```
  class DismissSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
      override func perform() {
          let animated = (source as? OptionalAnimation)?.animateDismiss ?? true
          sourceController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(animated, completion: nil)
      }
  }
  ```

  Where

  ```
  protocol OptionalAnimation {
      var animateDismiss: Bool { get }
  }
  ```

  And, your originating view controller would (a) conform to this protocol; and (b) set the `animateDismiss` property.
- Frankly, if you're just calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated`/`dismiss` in your `perform` method, I'd discourage you from using a segue like this. You generally would not use a segue for dismissing at all and just call `dismissViewControllerAnimated`/`dismiss` from a `@IBAction` in the view controller from which you are dismissing. You can then set the `animated` flag as you see fit more directly.

  Or if you did want to use a segue, you'd use an unwind segue. You could, for example, have one unwind segue with animation and one without (which you set in IB) and just initiate whichever was appropriate.
- And if you were doing custom animation, you'd generally use custom transitions (see WWDC 2013 [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/)). Then you have control over what animations you do or do not want to perform. Clearly, this is more complicated, but if you're doing custom animations, this is the way to tackle it.