# iOS how long does a standard push segue take?

Tags: ios, segue

I want to create an animation that happens in the same amount of time that a push segue takes to occur. Anyone know how long it takes? It looks to be about 0.25 seconds. Also, with what option does the view typically animate? Is it .curveEaseIn? .curveEaseInOut?

Comment: There are proper ways for animating segues instead of trying to match the timing of a system segue. See [Custom segue transition animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384854/custom-segue-transition-animation), [A beginner's guide to animated custom segues in iOS8](https://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/) or [How to configure animated in custom segue in iOS using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544659/how-to-configure-animated-in-custom-segue-in-ios-using-swift).

Comment: We don't know why OP wants to know the timing and duration of the push animation so simply telling him to create his own push animations may be of no value to him. Unfortunately, I have also wondered timings and durations of iOS animations so that I can keep them in mind with my custom animations but I've never been able to find them. I've never seen Apple expose these values, unfortunately.